# Adding Character & Replace Separator on a GROUP_CONCAT

Tags: mysql, sql

I am using a GROUP_CONCAT to list our twitter users which works and they're separated by commas.  NULLIF is used because some of the twitter names within the database are blank. We use this within our select statement:

```
GROUP_CONCAT(NULLIF(c.name, "")) twitterUser
```

We then print it out using:

```
' . $res["twitterUser"] . '
```

This then gives the answer:

```
twitter1,twitter2,twitter3
```

I want to know how do I add a character (as in an @) before c.name and how do I remove the , separator and replace with a space?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do so ,in `GROUP_CONCAT` you can specify your `SEPARATOR` as you wish to

```
GROUP_CONCAT(
CASE WHEN c.name IS NOT NULL AND c.name <> '' THEN CONCAT('@',c.name) END
SEPARATOR ' ')
```

[Reference](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat)

Comment: I'm getting Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING

Comment: Is this error related to php ? i am guessing you are using php seeing $res and can you add the code you are trying

Comment: It is yes, there is quite a lot of code to add.  I have tried adding SEPARATOR before and get the same issue :\

Comment: Without viewing php code i can't tell you where exactly the error is but i guess you are mixing single and double quotes in query i have provided you example using single quote

Comment: That's what it was! I changed to double quotes and now works a treat!